# Persistant UTF-8 Invalid Byte Sequences

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We're running the latest version of Rails 3.2 and the mysql2 gem. Lately I've noticed a number of entries in our error log, all originating from views:

`ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

As it turns out, users are persisting characters such as `\xED\xA0\xBC` to our database, and this is causing views to break.

I've done an extensive amount of research on this and have not found an solid answer yet. They all seem to address this from the Rails app side. I've already written a Rack middleware that sanitizes POST and PUT requests for characters like this, which I'd be happy to share, but I'm left wondering if there's a deeper problem going on here that I'm not addressing.

All of our MySQL tables have their collation set to `utf8_general_ci`. So I'm left wondering, then, how on Earth are these illegal characters getting into our database in the first place? Is there a way to make MySQL drop invalid characters like this? Or is this something I'm really left defending against in our app?

Comment: what version of ruby?